# Sizeof(char[]) in C

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof

Consider this code:

```
 char name[]="123";
 char name1[]="1234";
```

And this result

```
The size of name (char[]):4
The size of name1 (char[]):5
```

Why the size of `char[]` is always plus one?

Comment: The strings are NUL-terminated, which requires one extra byte.

Comment: Correct, however note you can also initialize UNterminated strings (don't!) `char name[8] = "12345678"; sizeof(name) = 8; name[8] = random!!`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As Michael pointed out in the comments the strings are terminated by a zero. So in memory the first string will look like this

```
"123\0"
```

where `\0` is a single char and has the ASCII value 0. Then the above string has size 4.

If you had not this terminating character, how would one know, where the string (or `char[]` for that matter) ends? Well, indeed one other way is to store the length somewhere. Some languages do that. C doesn't.

Comment: Ok but why?can you explain more?

Comment: Nitpicking on "*Then the above string has size 4.*" if defined like `char s= [] = "123\0";` it would have size of 5 ... :-)

Answer (score 28):

Note the difference between `sizeof` and `strlen`. The first is an operator that gives the size of the whole data item. The second is a function that returns the length of the string, which will be less than its `sizeof` (unless you've managed to get string overflow), depending how much of its allocated space is actually used.

In your example

```
char name[]="123";
```

`sizeof(name)` is 4, because of the terminating `'\0'`, and `strlen(name)` is 3.

But in this example:

```
char str[20] = "abc";
```

`sizeof(str)` is 20, and `strlen(str)` is 3.

Comment: Even better than my own answer :-), +1

Comment: Also 'strlen' is instanced at run-time and so if you are using an array with fixed size (as in the case) it's a good idea to prefer 'sizeof' in order to safe little milliseconds of program time.

Comment: I'd always prefer the one that is correct, not the one that is faster. And the savings will be nanoseconds, not milliseconds. But also, many compilers are smart enough to figure out themselves that in the example strlen (str) is 3 and there is no need to call it.

Comment: IMO this should be the accepted answer as looks like OP doesn't know  the difference and what they are used for.

Answer (score 8):

In C, strings are stored as arrays of `char`s.  With a recognised terminating character (`'\0'` or just `0`) you can pass a pointer to the string, with no need for any further meta-data.  When processing a string, you read chars from the memory pointed at by the pointer until you hit the terminating value.

As your array initialisation is using a string literal:

```
char name[]="123";
```

is equivalent to:

```
char name[]={'1','2','3',0};
```

If you want your array to be of size 3 (without the terminating character as you are not storing a string, you will want to use:

```
char name[]={'1','2','3'};
```

or

```
char name[3]="123";
```

(thanks alk)
which will do as you were expecting.

Comment: "*If you want your array to be of size 3  ...*" you could also do `char name[3] = "123"`.

Comment: @alk Thanks, I forgot that one.

Comment: Although char name[3] = "123" means there is no trailing nul character, which means for example strlen (name) is likely to crash or worse.

Comment: @gnasher729 yes. Though as the intention is to generate an array of chars without the null terminator (and not a string) you would not expect `strlen()` to be run on it.  Personally, unless I'm running a large scale application and getting alignment or cache misses with lots of arrays like this, I will happily take the extra char in my array, so that this would not happen, even accidentally.  I probably should have used `char array[]` in my examples (as "name" implies a string) but I chose to keep the Questions naming.

Answer (score 3):

Because there is a null character that is attached to the end of string in C.

Like here in your case

```
name[0] = '1'
name[1] = '2'
name[2] = '3'
name[3] = '\0'

name1[0] = '1'
name1[1] = '2'
name1[2] = '3'
name1[3] = '4'
name1[4] = '\0'
```

Answer (score 2):

A `String` in C (and in, probably, every programming language - behind the scenes) is an array of characters which is terminated by `\0` with the ASCII value of 0.

When assigning: `char arr[] = "1234";`, you assign a string literal, which is, by default, null-terminated (`\0` is also called null) as you can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t.aspx).

To avoid a null (assuming you want just an array of `char`s and not a string), you can declare it the following way `char arr[] = {'1', '2', '3', '4'};` and the program will behave as you wish (`sizeof(arr)` would be 4).

Comment: Not every programming language. In languages where strings are counted sequences, a NUL after the string, if there, is only to minimize problems with interop code (like C) that doesn't respect the count.

Comment: @TomBlodget By saying 'probably', I said that I'm not sure - I was actually quite sure that there are some programming languages where strings are not null-terminated.

Answer (score 1):

```
name = {'1','2','3','\0'};
name1 = {'1','2','3','4','\0'};
```

So

```
sizeof(name) = 4;
sizeof(name1) = 5;
```

`sizeof` returns the size of the object and in this case the object is an array and it is defined that your array is 4 bytes long in first case and 5 bytes in second case.

Answer (score 1):

In C, string literals have a null terminating character added to them.

Your strings,

```
 char name[]="123";
 char name1[]="1234";
```

look more like:

```
 char name[]="123\0";
 char name1[]="1234\0";
```

Hence, the size is always plus one. Keep in mind when reading strings from files or from whatever source, the variable where you store your string, should always have extra space for the null terminating character.

For example if you are expected to read string, whose maximum size is 100, your buffer variable, should have size of 101.

Answer (score 0):

Every string is terminated with the char nullbyte '\0' which add 1 to your length.

Comment: Well, not always. For example, `char name[3] = "123";` is not NUL-terminated.